# execute "vagrant up" from ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I have an ROR application from which I am trying to execute **vagrant up** command in the following way **system("vagrant up")**

I am getting the below error

```
Vagrant experienced a version conflict with some installed plugins!
This usually happens if you recently upgraded Vagrant. As part of the
upgrade process, some existing plugins are no longer compatible with
this version of Vagrant. The recommended way to fix this is to remove
your existing plugins and reinstall them one-by-one. To remove all
plugins:
    rm -r ~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json ~/.vagrant.d/gems
Note if you have an alternate VAGRANT_HOME environmental variable
set, the folders above will be in that directory rather than your
user's home directory.
The error message is shown below:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    vagrant (= 1.7.2) x86-mingw32 depends on
      bundler (< 1.8.0, >= 1.5.2) x86-mingw32
  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.10.0.pre.2)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
Could not find gem 'bundler (< 1.8.0, >= 1.5.2) x86-mingw32', which is required by gem 'vagrant (= 1.7.2) x86-mingw32', in any of the sources.
```

I have tried to do  **gem install bundler** , it always installs bundler 1.9.9

If i try to execute **vagrant up** from command line it works fine
Below are the versions which I am using

```
ruby -> 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]
Vagrant -> 1.7.2
Rails -> 4.2.1
```

Any sort of help is much appreciated

Comment: Just a hunch, try using ruby's [`exec()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) instead of `system()` [which runs in a subshell](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)